# Missing Dependencies for Python in Conda in MMA 12.1 in Windows 10

Tags: python, external-calls

I tried to run python code in MMA 12.1 on my Windows 10 computer. However, it seems that the python in conda has MissingDependencies, as shown below.

[image]

According to this FAQ thread, https://support.wolfram.com/42342?src=mathematica, this suggests that I need to install the pyzmq package to fix this issue. However, the pyzmq is already contained in conda...

[image]

So, what should I do to make the Conda python work in MMA 12.1?

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved!

With the help of *Wolfram Support* team, I figured out how to get the `conda` work in *Mathematica* in windows.

**1._** `conda`'s installation and library path is not in *Mathematica*'s default Path. So we need to manually add the path by:

```
SetEnvironment[
    "PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> ";" <> "C:\\\Users\\\user\\\AppData\\\Local\\\Continuum\\\anaconda3"
]
```

(for python executable)

```
SetEnvironment[
    "PATH" -> Environment["PATH"] <> ";" <> "C:\\\Users\\\user\\\AppData\\\Local\\\Continuum\\\anaconda3\\\Library\\\bin"
]
```

(for pyzmq library).

Just replace the path above with your own `conda` path.

**2._** (re-)Register the conda in MMA by:

```
RegisterExternalEvaluator[
    "Python", "C:\\\Users\\\user\\\AppData\\\Local\\\Continuum\\\anaconda3\\\python.exe"
]
```

again replace the path above with your own `conda` path.

**3._** Now the `conda` should work in *Mathematica*. You can check it by

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]
```